# Question about finding the relationship of a homomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\phi : \Bbb Z \to S_8$ be a homomorphism such that $$\phi(1) = (1 4 2 6)(3 5 8).$$
$(a)$ Calculate $\phi(3)$ and $\phi(73)$.

I'm confused as to how to calculate $\phi(3)$ and $\phi(73)$ from just this one condition.

Answer (score 3):

First off, notice that $\phi(n)=\phi(n\cdot 1)=\phi(1)^n\in S_8$ for all integers $n$ because this is the most fundamental property of a homomorphism:  **The addition of the group** $\mathbb Z$ **becomes composition of the group** $S_8$ **under this homomorphism**.

Furthermore $\phi(1)=(1426)(358)$ is a product of $2$ disjoint cycles which do not interfere with the workings of each other (aka they commute). Doing $(358)^3$ gives you the identity because it is a $3$ cycle and doing $(1426)^4$ gives you the identity because it is a $4$ cycle.

So let me do $\phi(1)^3$ and perhaps you could show me how to do the other (which is actually easier):

$$\phi(1)^3=((1426)(358))^3=(1426)^3(358)^3=(1426)^{4-1}=(1426)^4(1426)^{-1}=(1426)^{-1}=(6241).$$

A good exercise is to carefully verify every equality in the chain of equalities based on the properties I just rattled off in the first and second paragraph.

Comment: Note that $(1426)(358)$ has order $12$, which simplifies computing $\phi(73)$.

Comment: So ϕ(73) = ϕ(1)73=((1426)(358))73=(1426)73(358)73=(1426)72+1(358)72+1=(1426)1(358)1=(1426)(358) ? Is this right? Since 4 divides 72 and 3 divides 72 do they get eliminated as the identity?

Comment: @bcolbert01 Bingo!